# Updating csi-driver without stopping

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform

I'm now facing this.

```
  # module.eks_volume_provisioning.aws_eks_addon.csi_driver will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_eks_addon" "csi_driver" {
      ~ addon_version            = "v1.25.0-eksbuild.1" -> "v1.28.0-eksbuild.1"
        id                       = "kmx-dev:aws-ebs-csi-driver"
        tags                     = {}
        # (7 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

this is my terraform plan output. It wants to update csi-driver to a newer one.

I'm curious that it would update csi-driver without stopping. Is it possible to affect my services that are using persistent volume?